# Storing a list in panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to save a list in a pandas DataFrame, but I am not able to achieve that all the time.

I will try to explain the issue with code.

With the following code I can save a list in pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index = ['R1'], columns = ['C1'])

df1.loc['R1', 'C1'] = [1, 2]
print(df1.loc['R1', 'C1'])
```

but when I save the dataframe in parquet or csv and then read the dataframe from there, I am not able to save a list in the dataframe-

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index = ['R1'], columns = ['C1'])
df1.loc['R1', 'C1'] = 1

df1.to_parquet('exampleTable.parquet')

df2 = pd.read_parquet('exampleTable.parquet')
df2.loc['R1', 'C1'] = [1, 2]
```

For the above code, I receive the following error-

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_73084/2822717306.py", line 9, in <cell line: 9>
    df2.loc['R1', 'C1'] = [1, 2]

  File "/home/p/Documents/james-python-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 849, in __setitem__
    iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)

  File "/home/p/Documents/james-python-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1830, in _setitem_with_indexer
    self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)

  File "/home/p/Documents/james-python-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2070, in _setitem_single_block
    self.obj._mgr = self.obj._mgr.setitem(indexer=indexer, value=value)

  File "/home/p/Documents/james-python-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 394, in setitem
    return self.apply("setitem", indexer=indexer, value=value)

  File "/home/p/Documents/james-python-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 352, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)

  File "/home/p/Documents/james-python-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 1065, in setitem
    values[indexer] = casted

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I trided changing the data type of the dataframe but that was not useful

```
df2 = df2.astype(int)
```

1. What is causing the error when I load a table from parquet and is there a way to fix it?
2. My objective is to save data structures (such as lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries, numpy array, DataFrame) in a tabular form. If there an alternate solution to that, I am open to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you read the DataFrame from the parquet file then data type will be an integer but you are trying to assign a list data type object to it

Answer (score 0):

Reading from parquet will assign an integer type to your column. Manually convert the column to object before assigning non-integers:

```
df2['C1'] = df2['C1'].astype(object)
df2.loc['R1', 'C1'] = [1, 2]
```

Or:

```
df2 = pd.read_parquet('exampleTable.parquet').astype({'C1': object})
df2.loc['R1', 'C1'] = [1, 2]
```

Output:

```
        C1
R1  [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

tl:dr: Use ast.literal_eval after the read.

new_df["list_after_read"] = new_df["list"].apply(ast.literal_eval)

To convert a string back to a list in a Pandas DataFrame, you can use the literal_eval function from the ast (Abstract Syntax Trees) module. This function evaluates a string containing a Python literal (e.g., a list, tuple, dictionary, etc.) and returns the corresponding Python object.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["list"] = [["123","45"],["456", "678"]]
df["list_types"] = df["list"].apply(lambda x: str(type(x)))

df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, header=True)
new_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

new_df["list_after_read"] = new_df["list"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
new_df["list_after_read_type"] = new_df["list_after_read"].apply(lambda x: str(type(x)))
new_df
```

Output:

```
id list           list_types     list_after_read read_type_after read_type_of_list_first_item
0  ['123', '45']  <class 'list'> [123, 45]       <class 'list'>  <class 'str'>
1  ['456', '678'] <class 'list'> [456, 678]      <class 'list'>  <class 'str'>
```

By looking at this output you can think that the datatype of the values inside the list changed from a string to an integer, but if we check the datatype (read_type_of_list_first_item), it returns original str datatype.

This answer was taken from: https://saturncloud.io/blog/pandas-dataframe-stored-list-as-string-how-to-convert-back-to-list/